# Error : Installation of blur-admin with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, blur-admin

I want to install blur admin theme with angular js

I have follow steps to install blur admin theme from below site

```
https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/
```

I got the error as below ,
[image]

I find for solution for that and found below commands to run

```
npm update
npm install gulp-sass
```

then again run

```
gulp serve
```

but still same error I got

In my system git is installed and my nodejs version is 8.9.4

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not installed **`gulp-sass`** module.

Install it by running `npm` following command

```
npm install gulp-sass@latest --save-dev
```

Make sure you have deleted **`node_modules`** folder before install module.

Comment: I have installed gulp-sass by npm install gulp-sass command but it not worked. but above solution for latest version installation it worked.